# VSCode, Docker, Rails debugging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, debugging, visual-studio-code

New to VSCode i tried to debug an existing Rails app that Runs within Docker (started via docker compose)

I followed the instructions on https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby (installed the gems + extension, launch config).

I can start puma and see breakpoints being added

```
some-app_1  | 1: <breakpointAdded no="3" location="...../some-app/app/controllers/hello_worlds_controller.rb:4"/>
```

But when I hit the above controller with a request, the breakpoint does not kick in (request just passes).

- Ruby: 2.7
- Rails: 6.1
- cmd (docker-compose.yml): "rdebug-ide --debug --host 0.0.0.0 --port 1234 -- bin/rails server -p 5000 -b 0.0.0.0"

launch config:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "some-App",
        "type": "Ruby",
        "request": "attach",
        "remoteHost": "127.0.0.1",
        "remotePort": "1234",
        "remoteWorkspaceRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      }
    ]
  }
```

There is nothing in the Ruby output channel or in the logs of the container.

I assume I am doing something wrong? Or something is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your ***remoteWorkspaceRoot*** it's pointing to your local machine, the debugger needs to know what file should he watch to break inside the docker container

For example, if inside your docker container, your project is on "/app", you should change your ***remoteWorkspaceRoot*** variable to "/app"

In console you should see

```
some-app_1  | 1: <breakpointAdded no="3" location="your-docker-path-to-the-project/some-app/app/controllers/hello_worlds_controller.rb:4"/>
```

instead of

```
some-app_1  | 1: <breakpointAdded no="3" location="...../some-app/app/controllers/hello_worlds_controller.rb:4"/>
```

and that should work fine if you are not using Windows (backlashes compatibility)

Comment: Thank you!

Fixed the remoteWorkspaceRoot and breakpoint was hit, i have a working console, and can inspect variables. Neat.

Comment: @Pascal please accept the answer so others know your issue was solved